# How can I count the number of time each distinct value occurs in a column and then store the value pairs in a two dimensional array?

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I have a table named abc which has columns c1,c2,c3.
I want to find out number of time each distinct value occurs and store it in a 2 dimensional array. 
It should look like :

```
 {
     value1, count1,

     value2, count2,

     value3, count3,
}
```

Comment: do you know what values to look for or do you have to get them from data? Basically  - are they predefined?

Comment: are you using PHP?

Comment: I ma using sql.

Comment: yes, the data is inside the table. predefined. I just have to take it out of it and put it into a two dimentional array

Comment: Where will you store / work with 2 dimensional array?

Comment: i will take these values and store it into another table, but only the frequency of distinct values

Comment: I'd recommend you to look at this example: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby

Comment: but in this example it is not creating an 2d array which i can later use for further manipulations .

Comment: it is a 2D table, same as 2D array, if you want to work with it as an array you have to use programming like PHP

Comment: SELECT COUNT(CustomerID), Country
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country;                    How am i gonna access this table since in the above code it has not named the table which will store these values ?

Comment: Please post the definition of the structure you need to populate. This will help people to build a solution taht works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1,count(col1) from abc group by col1
union all
select col2,count(col2) from abc group by col2
union all
select col3,count(col3) from abc group by col3
```

Comment: This solution does not create a two dimensional array.

Comment: @user3769820: You can have a look at collections in Oracle. Or else you can insert the output of the query given in the answer into a table.

Comment: can u tell me how can i insert the output of the quey to a table

Comment: `INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE SELECT * FROM SOME_OTHER_TABLE`. This is the basic syntax.

Comment: You need to learn basic SQL. You can have a look at [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php)